# django JsonResponce gives json with slaches as a string

Tags: python, django

I use django for sending some data in json but i get json string with slashes

This code

```
class LevelsSerialiser(Serializer):
    def end_object(self, obj):
        # self._current has the field data
        indent = self.options.get("indent")
        if not self.first:
            self.stream.write(",")
            if not indent:
                self.stream.write(" ")
        if indent:
            self.stream.write("\n")
        data = {}
        data['id'] = self._value_from_field(obj, obj._meta.pk)
        data.update(self._current)
        json.dump(data, self.stream, **self.json_kwargs)
        self._current = None


class LevelsView(MainView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = vocabulary.customserializers.LevelsSerialiser();
        return JsonResponse(serializer.serialize(vocabulary.models.Level.objects.all()), safe=False)
```

gives me this json with slashes as string

```
"[{\"id\": 1, \"name\": \"Upper Intermediate\", \"code\": \"B1\"}]"
```

But i need something like this,

```
[
   {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Upper Intermediate",
      "code": "B2"
   }
]
```

what i am doing wrong?

Comment: JsonResponse([1, 2, 3], safe=False)

Comment: What is that `Serializer` base class you're inheriting from? It looks like you're doing double encoding.

Comment: Problem might be in dumping to stream. Does `HttpResponse` produce such behavior?

Comment: i have checked
 if i use this
return HttpResponse(serializers.serialize(vocabulary.models.Level.objects.all()),content_type='application/json');
it works well

Answer (score 0):

I am still not sure what is the reason but

```
return HttpResponse(serializers.serialize(vocabulary.models.Level.objects.all()),content_type='application/json');
```

gives

```
[{"id": 1, "name": "Upper Intermediate", "code": "B1"}]
```